# Is the work done by external force in moving a charge between two points given by $W=q\Delta V_e,$ where $V_e$ is due to electrostatic force?

Tags: electrostatics, energy, potential, work

In this book at [page 693](https://archive.org/details/physicsforscient0000serw/page/692/mode/2up?view=theater) at the bottom, it is written that the work done by an external agent (non-conservative) in moving a charged particle of charge $q$ between two points with electrical potential difference $\Delta V_e$ (see equation 25-3) is $W=q\Delta V_e,$ (equation $25-4$) provided if the charge has the same speed at the end and starting point. But I think that's wrong since by the work-energy theorem $W=q\Delta V_e +m\Delta V_g$ must be correct where $\Delta V_g$ is potential change due to gravitational force and $m$ is the mass of the charge. The book ignored gravity. Hence the equation is wrong. But the same thing has been written in many books. Hence I may be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the example of gravitational force, which is conservative. A gravitational force will cause a change in the gravitational potential energy of the system and consequently a change in gravitational potential.

The gravitational potential difference would be defined as: $$\Delta V_g = \frac{\Delta U_g}{m}$$
and consequently would have units: $$[\Delta V_g] = \frac{J}{\text{kg}}$$
Hence, the term $q\Delta V_g$ would not have units of work ($J$), and you cannot consider the equation to be $W_\text{ext} = q\Delta V_c$.

Rather (in our case), it would be $$W = q\Delta V_e + m\Delta V_g = \Delta U_E + \Delta U _g $$

which is a familiar reduction of the principle of conservation of energy for an isolated system.

Hope this helps.

---

The change in gravitational potential energy is neglected often because the charges in consideration have a negligible mass, and also because the electric force is *much* larger in magnitude compared to the gravitational force.

Comment: I edited the question, it was silly mistake. But the book is still wrong.

Comment: Yes, most books ignore gravitational effects, because the charges in consideration have a negligible mass. But if you intend to be extremely specific, you are right

Comment: But this equation is used to give meaning to the electrical potential energy of a system, which is a very important and useful concept, how could they do it? This is also written in Griffith as well.

Comment: See my edit, the electrostatic force is much larger in magnitude compared to the gravitational force, usually of the order $~10^{30}$ between particles like protons and other point charges